# Sonos self-test: exception during secure renegotiation test

Tags: sonos

We are running the Sonos Self-Test Suite to validate our service implementation. All tests are green except the "ssl_validation test_support_secure_renegotiation". The related output from the test is

```
[FAIL] SONOS.sonos.workflow.fixture.ssl_validation - There was an exception while scanning the domain (<our domain>) for secure session renegotiation: sslyze.utils.ctSSL.errors.SSLErrorSSL - error:140E0197:SSL routines:SSL_shutdown:shutdown while in init
```

Our domains supports secure renegotiation accorning to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html, also the output of `sslyze --reneg <our domain>` seems to be OK:

```
SCAN RESULTS FOR <our-domain>:443 - <our-ip>.
-------------------------------------------------

 * Session Renegotiation:
       Client-initiated Renegotiation:    OK - Rejected
       Secure Renegotiation:              OK - Supported
```

Any suggestion how to get rid of the error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Our ssl tests on self test currently have a few problems. We have filed bugs. In the meantime, you can ignore this specific ssl error.

Comment: Is this still an issue? I am getting the same error, although secure renegotiation seems to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be still an issue. I am getting this error, too:

> FAIL There was an exception while scanning the domain (smapi.xxx.xx) for secure session renegotiation: sslyze.utils.ctSSL.errors.SSLErrorSSL - error:140E0197:SSL routines:SSL_shutdown:shutdown while in init

But via sslyze it seems to be fine:

```
sslyze --reneg smapi.xxx.xx
```

> - Session Renegotiation:
>
>   Client-initiated Renegotiation:    OK - Rejected
>
>   Secure Renegotiation:              OK - Supported

And https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest says:

> Secure Renegotiation  Supported
>
> Secure Client-Initiated Renegotiation     No
>
> Insecure Client-Initiated Renegotiation   No